# How do you write an MIT Scheme macro to return a lambda form?

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme, sicp

I'm baffled by trying to create the equivalent of this trivial (in Common Lisp) macro in MIT Scheme:

```
(defmacro funcify (exp)
    `(lambda (x) ,exp))
```

This is for a simple personal project, a numerical equation solver based on the functions built in the second SICP lecture.   I don't care that this macro is not "safe" or "hygienic" or will capture a variable if  the exp references any symbols other than 'x.   I'd like to be able to write

```
(solv '(* 60 x) '(* 90 (- x 1)))
```

where solv is:

```
(define (solv lh-exp rh-exp)
    (solve (funcify lh-exp) (funcify rh-exp)))
```

instead of having to type

```
(solve (lambda (x) (* 60 x)) (lambda (x) (* 90 (- x 1))))
```

But can't figure out how to do this using MIT Scheme syntax-rules.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
(define-syntax funcify
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((funcify y) (lambda (x) y))))
;Value: funcify

(funcify x)
;Value 17: #[compound-procedure 17]

((funcify x) 10)
;Unbound variable: x
```

I've tried other things probably not worth mentioning involving `eval` but to no avail.

Also, references to good tutorials (not references) on Scheme's macro system that start with small simple examples and build up, with ample commentary, and in particular show how to convert backquote-comma style LISP macros (which to me are highly intuitive) to Scheme's syntax macro system would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do basically the same thing as with `defmacro` by using [explicit-renaming macros](https://www.gnu.org/s/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Explicit-Renaming.html#Explicit-Renaming).  The only significant difference is that you will have to destructure the input form yourself:

```
(define-syntax funcify
  (er-macro-transformer
    (lambda (form rename cmp)
      (let ((exp (cadr form)))
        `(,(rename 'lambda) (x) ,exp)))))
```

Comment: +1.  Thanks a bunch.  define-syntax is entirely bewildering but I suspect it very powerful, I'd like to learn it better, any references to coming up to speed on it?    I'm accepting your answer because it gives a funcify that works in MIT Scheme, I wish I could also accept Chris's answer because it also points out that solv must be a syntax-rules macro as well.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484094/what-are-the-advantages-of-scheme-macros has a link to a book with chapters teaching scheme macros at the level I'm looking for: Shriram Krishnamurthi's http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/plai-2007-04-26.pdf chapters 36 and 37

Answer (score 7):

It cannot be done in `syntax-rules`. End of story.

Injecting an arbitrary identifier (`x`, in your case) into the output expression requires breaking hygiene, and `syntax-rules` does not provide any means to break hygiene. You will need to use a lower-level macro system to do this. MIT Scheme uses explicit renaming (see Matthias Benkard's answer), but for other Scheme implementations that use `syntax-case`, you can do it thus:

```
(define-syntax funcify
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      ((_ body)
       (with-syntax ((x (datum->syntax stx 'x)))
         #'(lambda (x)
             body))))))
```

The key is the `(datum->syntax stx 'x)` bit, which injects the symbol `x` as if it were in the syntactic context of the `funcify` invocation.

By the way, your `solv` must also be a macro, not a procedure, but at least it can be a `syntax-rules` macro:

```
(define-syntax solv
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ lhs rhs) (solve (funcify lhs) (funcify rhs)))))
```

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for your answer, and for pointing out that solv must be a macro as well.  Macros are tricky to begin with, but Scheme syntax-* macros are probably the hardest thing I've seen so far in a language, and I've been programming (mostly blubs, but I did my MS thesis in CL) for 30+ years.

Comment: @Bogatyr: Wait till you get to continuations. ;-) (Seriously, though, Scheme is a pretty big language, conceptually, notwithstanding that the R5RS spec fits within "50 pages".)